# hoverIntent use id of hovered element to change class

Tags: css, jquery-hover, hoverintent

I'm trying to reveal content using [hoverIntent](http://tournasdimitrios1.wordpress.com/2011/09/25/an-introduction-to-the-hoverintent-jquery-plugin/)  without writing specific conditions for each id. I would like to have the id passed to the mouse in settings so I can reveal content selected by adding characters to the id + '-x'.

I have tried a few ways to get the div I'm hovering over but these usually end up returning all the information of all the divs with the class "box".

Is there a parent, child thing I should be doing? I don't understand it really but feel like this is the situation it would helpful in.

```
<div id="id-first-div" class="box">Trigger 1</div>
<div id="id-second-div" class="box">Trigger 2</div>

<div id="id-second-div-x" class="hide">Hidden Bullet 1</div>
<div id="id-first-div-x" class="hide">Hidden Bullet 2</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#id-first-div").hoverIntent(slide_right_settings);
    $("#id-second-div").hoverIntent(slide_right_settings);
});

var slide_right_settings={
    sensitivity: 4,
    interval: 1500,
    timeout: 5000,
    over: mousein_triger,
    out: mouseout_triger
};  

function mousein_triger(){
    var id = this.id; // I'm pretty sure I'm going wrong here 
    $(id + '-x').addClass('reveal');
    $(id + '-x').removeClass('hide');
}

function mouseout_triger() {
    $(id +'-x').addClass('hide');
    $(id +'-x').removeClass('reveal');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//hover intent opening and closing
var slide_right_settings={
    over: mousein_triger,
    out: mouseout_triger
};  

//default id is home
var id = "home";

function mousein_triger(){
//updates id to the one triggering
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + id + '-x').addClass('reveal');
    $('#' + id + '-x').removeClass('hide');
}

function mouseout_triger() {
    $('#' + id +'-x').addClass('hide');
    $('#' + id +'-x').removeClass('reveal');                
}
```

Still not sure if this is the best way to achieve this, but it's working.. I'm sure it could be improved a lot.

Answer (score 0):

place the `var id = this.id;` outside the function